# Merging pandas dataframe on unique values in a column

Tags: pandas

I have a `df1` as:

[image]

There are a lot of duplicating values for `SUBJECT_ID` as shown in the picture. I have a `df2` to merge from, but I want to merge it on unique `SUBJECT_ID`. For now I only know how to merge to entire `SUBJECT_ID` through this code:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1,df2[['SUBJECT_ID', 'VALUE']], on='SUBJECT_ID', how='left' )
```

But this will merge on every `SUBJECT_ID`. I just need unique `SUBJECT_ID`. Please help me with this.

Comment: Add code, errors, and data as text, not screenshots because [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and add text.

Comment: Please [create a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard), [edit] the question, and paste the clipboard into a code block or include synthetic data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: If there are so many duplicates, `.drop_duplicates` or `groupby`.

Comment: I'm told to not drop_duplicates tho

Comment: In copy and pasteable format what is df1 and df1 (include that in oyur question). Then, what is your desired output?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Like everyone is saying, create a short dummy dataframe using code so we can just copy/paste it instead of having to retype it. Example: 
`SUBJECT_ID = [31, 31, 31]` ... `GENDER = ['M', 'M', 'M']` ... etc. ... `df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(SUBJECT_ID, GENDER)), columns =['SUBJECT_ID', 'GENDER'])`

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find your answer with the [merge documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

It's not fully clear what you want, but here are some examples that may contain the answer you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
display(df1)

SUBJECT_ID = [31, 32, 33]
something_interesting = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(SUBJECT_ID, something_interesting)), 
                   columns =['SUBJECT_ID', 'something_interesting']) 
display(df2)
```

[image]

```
df_keep_all = df1.merge(df2, on='SUBJECT_ID', how='outer')
display(df_keep_all)
```

[image]

```
df_keep_df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='SUBJECT_ID', how='inner')
display(df_keep_df1)
```

[image]

```
df_thinned = pd.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), df2, on='SUBJECT_ID', how='inner')
display(df_thinned)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas drop function for it using this function you can remove all duplicate values for column or columns.

```py
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['SUBJECT_ID'])`
```